# Is it possible to change the view technology of angular?

Tags: angular, flutter, dart

Currently the view technology in angular is HTML+CSS which is what is present in the angular component. Is it possible to replace the view technology of angular to something different like flutter. So instead of HTML+CSS for a component, there will be widgets in the component.

This would help to utilise powerful structure and features of angular with the power of flutter for native mobile application. There is [angulardart](https://angulardart.dev/), but still it has HTML+CSS

Comment: Why do Flutter+angular, and not just Flutter?

Comment: I don't do flutter, but from the looks it's entirely different from what angular does with html/css, you should be using either or, but not both together.

Comment: @RémiRousselet , yes just flutter is good, I was just curious if this could be a possibility as angular has very good tooling ,code generation and powerful structure in place. Again I agree yes we can do that in flutter with some learning curve :)